# I need help in batch with the "If not defined (item) goto (item)" code

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, undefined

Im creating a parody of the command prompt with batch and everytime i put in an unknown command in the batch file like "JABSD" it just closes even though i already put the

```
if not defined (item) goto (item)
```

command. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
color 0a
echo Microbach Bachdos [version 9.9.bachcmd0a2pro]
echo Copybach (C) 1700 Microbach Corporbachtion. All Bachs reserved.
:commandbach
echo .
set "bachcmd="
set /p "bachcmd= C:\Bachusers\BACH)"
if not defined bachcmd goto invalidbcommand
REM error corrections
if /i "%bachcmd%"==" " (
:invalidbcommand
echo '%bachcmd% is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or .bach file.
goto commandbach
)
if /i "%bachcmd%"=="ACTBACH" (
echo Please use a valid number
echo ACTBACH symphony_number
)
REM commands
if /i "%bachcmd%"=="help" (
echo HELP                             Displays a list of Bach commands.
echo ACTBACH symphony_number          Plays the symphony number.
goto commandbach
)
if /i "%bachcmd%"=="ACTBACH 1" (
start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7JZB-lC_Hw
goto commandbach
)
if /i "%bachcmd%"=="ACTBACH 2" (
REM start (insert URL)
echo Cannot find the symphony number
goto commandbach
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF NOT DEFINED` only checks for the definition of a variable. In your case it will always be true because someone it entering a value.

To accomplish what you want, you need to place this line at the bottom of your script:

```
GOTO commandbach
```

This will essentially create an endless loop (until the user closes the window or presses Ctrl+C). You may want to consider adding an "exit" command so users can enter a command to quit your program.

Comment: Thanks, i now feel like an idiot for not thinking of this :P.